# Sitecore Include Files sort order broken

Tags: .net, sitecore, sitecore7

Suddenly, Lucene indexes at my Sitecore website got broken and after some investigation, I've noticed that Sitecore include files are "patching" web.config in non-alphabetical order.

John West mentioned in one of hist blog posts:

> Sitecore processes Web.config include files in alphabetical order (technically, the order returned by the Directory.GetFiles() method).

However, MSDN says:

> The order of the returned file names (from GetFiles()) is not guaranteed; use the Sort() method if a specific sort order is required.

What could cause that kind of issues? Is it something related to the server configuration?

Comment: as far as i know, include files should be patched in alphabetical order (unless specified in patch attribute). You should contact sitecore support to see if this is a bug

Comment: How do you know the patch includes are in the incorrect order, by viewing the showconfig.aspx page? Did you upgrade to SC7 recently? Either way, as Ahmed says, contact SC Support

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a trick that you can use if you need to ensure that your own config include is always included after all the other include files.
Make sure all the default and vendor `.config` files are located directly in the `/App_Config/Include` folder and then create one sub folder in which you place your own include file, for example `/App_Config/Include/Custom/MyConfig.config`.

This way your config include is always loaded last because files from the top-level folder are always returned first by the `Directory.GetFiles()` method.

Comment: That's a great tip, makes life much simpler and more obvious what is custom vs standard

Answer (score 0):

Plase check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) . The order of the returned file names is not guaranteed; use the Sort() method if a specific sort order is required. it say on MSDN.

But I know when you want to patch a patch, the naming of the file is important.
Example: You can patch  `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Lucene.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config`

by creating a new config file called `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Lucene.DefaultIndexConfigurationPatch.config` which will then be included in the final web.config section right after the original `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Lucene.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config.`

You can check your modification on config files with :

```
hostname/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx
```